# JPA/Hibernate entityManager.persist(..) makes the entity's collection to become null even though they are saved

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a PurchaseEntity that has a Set inside.
After doing entityManager.persist(purchaseEntity), purchaseEntity itself and purchaseItemEntity's are all saved to DB correctly.

But after that entityManager.persist(purchaseEntity) call, purchaseEntity.getItems() returns null.

Is this a normal behaviour of Hibernate provided entityManager.persist()?

Is there a way to keep the collection remain in the containing entity object after it's persisted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not a normal behavior. Furthermore, this is most certainly not Hibernate's doing - it has to be something in your code. Can you post your source?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That gave me enough hints to figure out what was wrong with our code. Cheers. :-)